# Motorola MACSBUG source code?

Tags: motorola-68000

Does anyone know of a source for Motorola's MACSBUG 68k monitor source code (which was the basis for the classic Mac debugger with the same name)?

I seem to remember it was available on the old Motorola BBS, but the only related code I could find on a mirror of the BBS are different debuggers (FBUG68K and VUBUG).

Comment: Maybe search also for `TUTOR` 'cause that was the name of the MACSBUG when used as a monitor for the MEX68KECB Singleboarder (M68K Educational Computer Board)  It's eventually a late offspring of the original MEX68KDM (68K Design Module) from 1979 - here it was still called MBUG or MACSbug.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The TUTOR source code is in fact part of the BBS mirror (and the source internally references the software as MACSBUG).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if a general MACSbug was ever available. AFAIR Motorola did supply it only to OEM. They even had a special manual for OEM manufacturers regarding the adaption of MACSbug I/O functions and adding new commands (like Apple did for `ES` (Exit to Shell) and `RB` (ReBoot)). Many of them gave the resulting product a name of their choice. Then again, being the micro computer industry of the 70s, they wouldn't have mind an adoption by anyone.

For example Corvus added it (now spelled [MACSBUG 68000](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/corvus/Corvus_Concept/manuals/7100-01387_Macsbug_68000_Debugger_Users_Guide_Mar83.pdf)) to their [Corvus Concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvus_Systems#Corvus_Concept). Or Dual Systems added it as default monitor (here spelled Macsbug) to their [CPU/68000](ftp://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dualSystems/Dual_CPU_68000_Users_Manual_1982.pdf) for the S100. Or Omnibyte who offered MACSbug as OB68KMACS for the [OB68K1A Multibus CPU](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/omnibyte/OB68K1A_1983.pdf) (*1,2).

Heck, even Motorola did:

On the MEX68KDM (Mororola 68K Design Module) from 1979, where it was originally designed for, it was called `MBUG`, while its later (1983?) incarnation with the MEX68KECB (M68K Educational Computer Board) was named `Tutor`. The manual included a reference to the now generalized MACSbugname.

So maybe search for either systems software and have a look for the manual.

**Edit:** The OP [has found](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/motorola-macsbug-source-code/5553#5553) the MEX68KECB directory on Bitsavers including [Tutor/MACSbug Manuals and Binaries](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/motorola/68000/MEX68KECB/).

---

*1 - It always amazes me how many various CPUs got glued onto bus systems never ment for them. Like 6502 or 2650 to S100 or NS32k or 68k to Multibus.

*2 - They also offered the more powerfull VERSAbug named OB68KVERSA

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Raffzahn's comments, I could confirm that TUTOR is in fact an early version of MACSBUG. It's available at [this Motorola BBS mirror ftp site](ftp://164.41.45.4/pub/os/embedded/misc/motorola/m68k/tutor.arc) as well as on [bitsavers](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/components/motorola/68000/MEX68KECB/). There is also [a version that can be assembled with gas](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jefftranter/68000/master/tutor/tutor13.s).